# trunk with 3com

Tags: networking

how can make trunk link in 3com baseline switch 2948 SFP plus

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by trunk.

In Cisco language, a trunk is a 802.1Q port that will tag VLANs. You can do this by activating 802.1Q.

In rest-of-the-world language, a trunk is an agregate of two ports. You take two physical ports and bond them together to have one logical port with twice the bandwidth. This goes along with protocols such as LACP.

Comment: i can do with cisco switch but how can configuration trunk in 3com 2948

Comment: look at the manual of your switch but it's called 802.1Q